# Opera issue with dragging imaging how to disable preview

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, opera

I have a set of images, say 9 in a 3x3 grid. I want users to mouse down on an image and drag it to another image within the grid to "Swap" or to drag it in-between two images to insert at point.

All's fine in IE, Chrome, FF, Safari. Opera though still shows the opaque "Preview" of the dragged image which I have successfully suppressed in all other browsers using `return false` for the `ondragstart` event. Also the image Opera returns is offset to the right by `100px` or so, probably something to do with my CSS.

However, I don't care about people copying my images, this is to provide functionality. I need the opaque drag not to show in Opera.

Comment: Maybe try setting the image to transparent as it's dragged? Set the image as the background of the container and make the container dragable? I seem to think the latter will work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using html5 d'n'd there's no way to prevent the drag feedback to show (the spec does not specify any at least IINM). You may want to call data transfer's setDragImage() and set the image to something neutral, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to provide HTML, CSS and JS you are using?
Do you handle d'n'd yourself or want to use HTML5 d'n'd (from 'return false' in ondragstart fragment I take you do it on your own as it seems you cancel ondragstart which cancels html5 d'n'd)? If you used addEventListener() to register for ondragstart you need to call preventDefault() to cancel d'n'd instead.